# php include not showing on browser refresh?

Tags: php, html

I have a lengthy nav bar which I've added to nav.php and I include it on each page to save time on editing, however I've noticed that if I refresh the page with an included nav.php upon the refresh the nav.php isn't being reloaded with the browser.

Anyone know why this might be or a possible way around it?

Thanks.

Comment: Show your code...

Comment: post your code with proper format

Comment: First read [mcve] please

Answer (score 0):

Use `include('path_to_file')` function in PHP.

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body> 
      <?php include('path_to_file/nav.php'); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't know how to use the editor well on this as I only signed up a few minutes ago. Essentially if I add    <?php include("nav.php"); ?> inside the header or the body tags the initial load of said page works fine, however if I hit F5 or use the browser buttons I lose the nav.php

Comment: @BenjaminPhillips Can you show your code? Just edit your post and paste your code. That really help me a lot.

Comment: this is sorted now, I think it was an error with the backend as it's now started working. Many thanks for the replies.

Comment: Glad you achieved your goal.